# Estimating pseudo-periodicity of signals

Tags: spectral-theory, signal-processing, periodic-functions

I have pressure data which are measured at a given point in a [standing wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standing_wave). These data(signals) are 'almost' sinusoidal in nature. Each cycle may slightly vary from the original signal i.e the amplitude and frequency of each cycle may be slightly greater or lesser than the (original signal intended by the system) mean signal. How do I calculate this deviation in each cycle? The data set is quiet large-750 Hz signal for 10 seconds. Is there any easier way to do it?

Comment: Short term fft?

Comment: so you are trying to perform varying-sine tracking. the easiest way if there is only one varying-sine $\displaystyle A(t) e^{i \omega(t) t + i\phi}$ is to search for the path of highest energy in the short-term Fourier transform, with dynamic programming, using the constraint that the path cannot change of frequency too fast, and that the amplitude is band-limited.  @N74

Comment: @user1952009 you almost elaborated my hint into an answer

Comment: @N74 : but after that, optimizing the process, and implementing "realistic constraints" is much more complicated. you might prefer a constant Q-transform (more or less the wavelet transform) if you consider a constraint such that high-frequency sines might change of frequency much faster than low-frequency ones. obviously, when there are also the harmonics and mixed-sines (a real life sound) it becomes even more complicated, and it is a research problem (it becomes multipitch estimation)

Comment: @N74 I want to estimate the deviation of each cycle. I cannot do fft for each cycle!

Comment: I was suggesting to observe the spectrogram of your data and then estimate the peak frequency and phase for each time slot. You hame many other options, for example a PLL if you want something continuously following your signal... but you will have a delay in the estimate. You have the data, so you must choose the best way; we just give suggestions.

Comment: I don't have any specific ideas about estimating the deviation each cycle, but this sounds like a bandwidth estimation problem more than anything else. But to do that for every single cycle though seems both difficult and inaccurate. You could estimate the center frequency and the phase then just do a difference between the recorded signal and an ideal signal at that center frequency. It doesn't sound promising to me though unless you are very, very oversampled.